# Form submit does not set POST-variable of number input

Tags: php, forms, session, post

got a little problem when submitting a form.

Form:

```
<form action='warenkorb_aktual.php' method="post">
```

PHP-snippet(warenkorb.php):

```
<?php
session_start();

if( !isset($_SESSION['menge']) ){
    $menge = '1'; //standard value
}
else{
    $menge = $_SESSION['menge'];
}
.
.
.
echo "

    <td class='produktpadding'>
        <input name='inputanzahl' value='" . $menge . "' id='inputanzahl' type='number' min='1' max='10' class='input_anzahl form-control' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <div >
          <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-refresh'></i></button>
        </div>
   </td>
";

.
.
.

?>
```

the warenkorb_aktual.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $menge = $_POST['inputanzahl'];
    $_SESSION['menge'] = $menge;
    header("Location: warenkorb.php");


?>
```

What i'm trying to achieve:

The number in the input field should be set by typing the number in the input field. After submitting the form, it should be setted with the warenkorb_aktual.php (for reasons). But this doesn't work

Comment: You are missing the `session_start();` in script `warenkorb.php`

Comment: session_start(); is included by an external file. just forgot to mention it

Comment: Try posting some real code, if you want some real help.

Comment: Fix your quotes in the echo ...

Comment: to which extent should I post code? I don't want to (and can't) post the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem.
First, what was the problem: 
I had several input fields on my site and each of them where in the same form (like above, but they were in a loop). The thing: all input fields had the same name, so the code (in warenkorb_aktual.php) always overrode the post-variable.

Fix: 
1)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['menge'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['menge'] as $einzel){
        $menge[] = $einzel;
    }
    print_r($_SESSION['menge']);
    unset($_SESSION['menge']);

}
```

2)

```
$i=0;
while(..condition..){
    if( !isset($_SESSION['menge']) ){
                            $menge[$i] = 1;
                        }
        .
        .
        .
    echo "

           <td class='produktpadding'>
              <input name='inputanzahl[]' value='" . $menge[$i] . "'  type='number' min='1' max='10' class='input_anzahl form-control' />
            </td>
            <td>
              <div >
                 <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-refresh'></i></button>
               </div>
            </td>

    ";
$i++;
}
```

I hope that this can help some people